# White noise generator transistor voltage question

Tags: transistors, audio, noise, generator

I have a very newbie question.

Here is a white noise generator schematic I'm using (from http://montalk.net/emwng.html)

[image: Basic white noise generator]

It all works fine. What I want to understand is why this works at 9V (and down to 8V) but under 8V the whole thing just stops generating noise. I was wondering if it's possible to do the same circuit running at 5v for example.

Thank you.

Comment: C5 is backwards in this schematic -- the curved end is the negative side for electrolytic capacitors and should be connected to the output jack. The flat side should be connected to the amplifier output. C3 is also backwards

Comment: You may find a different brand of transistor has a lower reverse Vbe breakdown voltage, either through searching atasheets or experiment. Got any Germanium transistors handy? (They are usually PNP so you'd have to reverse the voltages in that section)

Comment: jp314 thank you but I figured that one out when I built it.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I don't think I have any Germanium transistors but I will look up low Vbe transistors and order some. I did not realize that 6V breakdown voltage was what was making it not work under 8V. I still don't quite get that.

Comment: *reverse* Vbe ... the spec you need is actually called Vebo. I dug out an old databook and found a few with Vebo(min) = 3V. One is still available ... the 2N3663 aka NT107 http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/244741.pdf but expensive. Small-signal UHF transistors seem to be a good bet for others... The 2SC5662 is lower cost, http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1645349.pdf Having a Vebo(min) 3V doesn't tell you the actual breakdown voltage but may improve on the current 8V.

Comment: Thanks again Brian. I spent some time searching in transistor database and at this point I think it defeats the purpose of a simple circuit since none of the 3v transistors seem to be 'standard' enough to buy for cheap. I think I will just miniaturize my microcontroller solution.

Answer (score 2):

This circuit amplifies the noise caused by the transistor Emitter-Base junction avalanching. The reverse breakdown voltage is usually 6-7V so it definitely won't work at 5V.

If you want something to work from a 5V supply you can step up the 5V to ~9V, using something like an ICL7660 (charge pump) or a boost regulator, or you could use a totally different principle and build a PRNG (pseudo-random number generator) using a microcontroller.

Comment: Thank you.
I already have a microcontroller based generator and it works fine but it seemed like overkill for something like this. I wanted to create a very simple noise generator but I prefer plugging things in to USB/rechargeable usb vs 9volt battery.

So is the 6-7v the same for all transistors? Are there any transistors with this being lower?

Comment: Some RF transistors have low breakdown, but they don't specify the actual breakdown and even if it did break down the noise production might be disappointing. Unless someone has already tested this you would just have to try it with various parts.

Comment: Really, the [ICL7660](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/icl7/icl7660.pdf) is a really common cheap part and only requires 2 small capacitors to work (no inductors). It will give you -5V so you have 10V in total so it should work okay. Worth adding to your bag of tricks if it's not there already.